# Manipulating 2D arrays by changing the start index and incrementing by 2 using Higher Order functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

lets say I have a huge game board with 44 rows and 9 columns. It would look like this:

```
var rows = Array(44).join(' ').split('').map(function() { return Array(9); });
```

Using higher-order functions only( no for loops), how would I first, start the looping index at 1 for even columns, and second how would I increment by two to iterate.

Comment: What's wrong with using a `for` loop?

Comment: For even rows, you mean?

Comment: nothing really, I just want to try it with higher order functions

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
Array(44).join(' ').split('').map(function(row,rowIndex)
{
    return Array(9).join(' ').split('').map(function(column,columnIndex)
    {
        return columnIndex *2 + 1 - rowIndex%2 ;
    });
});
```

Comment: I plan to iterate of those indexes by placing a sprite object at those indexes like so;

`sprite = sprite.create(rowIndex,columnIndex)
column = sprite`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a not so pretty ecmascript 6 way:

```
var rows = Array(44).join(' ').split('').map(function() { return Array(9); });

Array.from(new Array(Math.floor(rows.length/2)), (x,i) => i*2+1).map(function(i){
  console.log(i,rows[i])
})
```

And not sure if this counts or not as a for loop:

```
[for (i of rows.keys()) if (i%2==1) i].map(function(i){
  console.log(i, rows[i])
})
```